# Mocking arguments passed through a yielding block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I am using Minitest to test some code that looks like this:

```
class MyClass
  self.my_method
    Faraday.post('https://example.com') do |req|
      req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
      req.body = '{}'
    end
  end
end
```

I want to write a test which uses `Minitest::Mock` to check which parameters are passed.

If it was called using regular syntax (e.g. `Faraday.post(args...)` without the `do |req|` block) I would test it like this:

```
mock_post = Minitest::Mock.new
mock_post.expect(:call, {"sample" => "res"}, "https://example.com")
Faraday.stub :post, mock_post do
  MyClass.my_method
end
```

However, I'm not sure how to check the request params that are passed in using `do |req|`. For example, how would I check that `req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json`?

Comment: It might be a better idea to use Webmock and test the actual behavior (that it sends the correct HTTP request) instead of the implementation. That way the test works no matter how you use Faraday or even if you swapped it for a completely different library.